# document.getElementsByTagName is working but same functionality is not working with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html

I was trying to change the color of placeholder of input tag using Javascript. I am able to achieve that if I use document.getElementsByTagName, but if I am using document.getElementById then it's not working.

HTML:

```
<input name="txtfirstName" type="text" id="input" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="button" name="Button1" value="Register" onclick="ChangePlaceHolderColor();" />
```

JavaScript (with document.getElementsByTagName):

```
function ChangePlaceHolderColor() {
    var textBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (textBoxes[i].type == "text") {
            if (textBoxes[i].value == "") {
                textBoxes[i].className += " Red";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

JavaScript (with document.getElementById):

```
function ChangePlaceHolderColor() {
    var textBoxes = document.getElementById("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (textBoxes[i].type == "text") {
            if (textBoxes[i].value == "") {
                textBoxes[i].className += " Red";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure why this is happening.

Comment: Don't downvote my question. I had a genuine doubt that is why I asked this.

Comment: Look carefully and note how `getElementById()` has `Element` without an "s". I.e. it's singular, only returns a single element instead of a list of elements like `getElementsByTagName()` returns.

Comment: You wouldn't have needed to ask this question if you actually had bothered to look up the specification for `getElementById()`. In other words, you didn't make the minimal necessary effort before asking the question, that's likely why you were downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getElementById returns only 1 element, it is not an array

```js
function ChangePlaceHolderColorx() {
    var textBoxes = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i = 0; i < textBoxes.length; i++) {
        if (textBoxes[i].type == "text") {
            if (textBoxes[i].value == "") {
                textBoxes[i].className += "Red";
            }
        }
    }
}


function ChangePlaceHolderColor() {
    var textBoxes = document.getElementById("input");
   
        if (textBoxes.type == "text") {
            if (textBoxes.value == "") {
                textBoxes.className += "Red";
            }
        }
    
}
```

```css
.Red{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<input name="txtfirstName" type="text" id="input" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="button" name="Button1" value="Register" onclick="ChangePlaceHolderColor();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change function `ChangePlaceHolderColor()` to:

```
function ChangePlaceHolderColor() {
    var textBoxes = document.getElementById("input");
    if (textBoxes.type == "text") {
        if (textBoxes.value == "") {
                textBoxes.className += " Red";
        }
    }
}
```

this is because [getElementByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) will return [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection) which you can treat as an Array, but [getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) will return only one element.

Answer (score 1):

getElementsByTagName will always return an array of HTML elements, whereas getElementsById will always return a single HTML element.

```
function ChangePlaceHolderColor() {
    //no loop because the return is one element.
    var textBoxes = document.getElementById("input");
        if (textBoxes.type == "text") {
            if (textBoxes.value == "") {
                textBoxes.className += " Red";
            }
        }

}
```

In HTML, element IDs must be unique on any given page.